# I dont know what i am doing wrong in the FindLargest Function

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to programming.
I am solving a problem and getting very absurd values.
Any Fix ?

Program Req Output :

> Write a function maxColumn which takes a matrix of any size. It should
> find the largest element in each column of the array. You have to
> store it in a single dimensional array and print the values on screen.
> For example, if the matrix has following elements is
>  1 4 8
>  9 1 6
>  5 7 2
> Your result array should contain following elements.
> Result[3] = {9,
> 7, 8}
>  Note: Here we are calling 2D array as matrix

My Code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Global Variables
const int rows = 100;
const int col = 100;
void findLargest(int arr[rows][col], int size)
{
    int Max[] = {0};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            Max[i] = arr[i][j];
            if (arr[i][j] > Max[i])
            {
                Max[i] = arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << Max[i] << " ";
    }
    
}

int main()
{
    int arr[100][100] = {0};
    int size = 0;

    cout << "Enter the size = ";
    cin >> size;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    cout << "Array input by User";
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Max of Each Column is = ";
    findLargest(arr, size);
}
```

> My Output : 
> Enter the size = 3 
> 1 2 3
>  4 5 6
>  9 8 7 
> Array input by User =
>
> 1 2 3 
>   4 5 6 
>   9 8 7 
>  Max of Each Column is = 3 1 10

Comment: Did you try to debug your program? In the nested for loop you have an extra `Max[i] = arr[i][j];` before the if, are you sure you want it there?

Comment: `int Max[]` -> `int Max[rows]`. But since this is supposedly C++ (not C) then consider using `std::vector`.

Comment: Besides, you are trying to find the max of each row here, not of each column

Comment: "int arr[100][100] = {0};" This fill only the first element with a single zero! In your case not important, as you read each value and overwrite the noninitialized ones. But take care that your used syntax did something totally different as you expect. Try out to use {1} and you will see that only index [0][0] caries a 1 and the rest is still something different...

Answer (score 4):

`int Max[] = {0};` should have a size, otherwise, you'll be printing garbage values.

Also, in your inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            Max[i] = arr[i][j];  // <-------
            if (arr[i][j] > Max[i])
            {
                Max[i] = arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

You're setting the maximum each time you scan a new element, and not when you see a bigger one.

Answer (score 0):

Just Figured it out.
Just Write any constant Value in

```
int Max[100] = {0};
```

Comment: It can't be "any" value. It must be `>= size`. Then you depend on a runtime value, so you should use an `std::vector` instead of an array, because C++ does not support variable length C arrays.